# Database Design to Handle Irregular Working Hours

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Time for work shift was same for my client but now they want one half day in their work shift. Or you can say they want different timings for wokshift. The table below contains single shift and time was given with that but now scenario is changed.

Currently my table is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `work_shift` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shift_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_from` time NOT NULL,
  `time_to` time NOT NULL
  KEY `biz_company_id` (`tbl_school_system_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample Data is:

```
1   Morning   08:00:00  15:00:00
2   Shift 1   07:40:00  14:30:00
```

One way is to make another table and save the days along with work shift FORIEGN KEY.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. The sample data would well fit into the table, wouldn't it? You may need to elaborate.

Comment: @stickybit Suppose Morning shift, it has some start and end time. and it always go like that whole week. But i want to make separate timing for every week day. What i know is that i should make another table and made that thing there with the work_shift_id as FK. I just asked that if there is any best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Shift table that contained an Id, Shift Name and any other attributes that would be common to the shift (regardless of when it started/ended). Then create a Shift Instance table that has Shift Id + date as its compound Primary Key with time_from and time_to as its attributes

Comment: Thanks but I altered the table and added time_from and time_to for every day like time_from_mon, time_to_mon etc.